# Can you make assertTrue error messages more specific?

Tags: java, testng, appium, assert, assertion

I use testNG's assertTrue quite a lot to verify for example if transactions are correct

```
public void verifyAmount(WebElement element, String someText){
assertTrue(element.getText().contains(someText));
}
```

and when it fails it says

```
java.lang.AssertionError: did not expect to find [true] but found[false]
```

Is it possible to change assertion error to say what exactly went wrong, not just true/false statement? Is it possible to make that message more specific?
Is there a way to make assertion error say :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: did not expect to find [10.000 $] but found[3000 $]
```

Comment: because it is not always truly equal, the element has additions to original string, so I have to use "contains"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could turn this:

```
public void verifyAmount(WebElement element, String someText){
assertTrue(element.getText().contains(someText));
}
```

into:

```
public void verifyAmount(WebElement element, String someText, String message){
assertTrue(element.getText().contains(someText), message);
}
```

and pass the error message you feel should be given there.

EDIT: I'm used to using other assert methods, which take the message as first param, but Long Nguyen is right in his answer: TestNG accepts the message as last parameter of the assertTrue.

Answer (score 6):

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.testng/testng/6.8.17/org/testng/Assert.html#assertTrue(boolean)

Take a look at the documentation, you can see that you can add a message after the condition.

`public static void assertTrue(boolean condition, String message)`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for answers, the

```
 assertTrue(string.contains(property), errorMessage);
```

did the job

Comment: Instead accept the answer of Stultuske. Nice seeing unittesting

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will fix your need.

```
public static void verifyAmount(WebElement element, String expectedSubstring) {
    String actualText = element.getText();
    Assert.assertTrue(actualText.contains(expectedSubstring),
            String.format("Expected element text to contain '%s', but found: '%s'", expectedSubstring, actualText));
}
```